# Change Entire body to italic with bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, css, bookmarklet

I am trying to make a (pointless) bookmarklet that changes the entire body to Italics. My code is this:

```
javascript:document.body.style.font-style: = italic;
```

Please explain to me why it isn't working and how I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `font-style` should be `fontStyle`
2. Remove `:`
3. Put `italic` in double quotes.

```js
document.body.style.fontStyle = "italic";
```

```html
JavaScript will make it Italic
```

Comment: is this the same with `font-size` and `fontSize`?

Comment: `document.body.style.fontSize` for `font-size`

Comment: so you take away the - and initial cap the second word?